# 3 sudo password errors

Tags: 12.10, password

[image: screen shot of terminal]After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, I forgot to disable cap-locks and have attempted to use the wronf sudo password three times.  Now when I attempt a sudo command , I get a message in part reads "HTTP request sent, awaiting response...200k OK". Sorry, I don't know how to add a screen shot to this message.

How can I recover my sudo passwore/access?

Comment: To capture the output just redirect it to a file. For example, if you want to capture the output of `sudo ls` just do `sudo ls > ~/somefile.log` (this creates the file with the output on your home directory). You can then put it online in http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you run sudo with wrong password should not happen anything other than the command not being run.

[image]

The error `HTTP request sent, awaiting response...200k OK` sounds like you are running a http service with sudo maybe `wget` or something, and you are getting the page, I may need more info than that.

Running sudo 3 times with the wrong password could not have changed your SU password even if you ran sudo on `sudo passwd root`. Unless you forgot the password which is another question, you should try again with the same password since it is the same password as before running sudo.

To add images click the edit button bellow your question(you can find it between share and flag) and follow the instruction as in the picture:

[image]

After entering the command

```
wget -O - https://d2t3ff60b2tol4.cloudfront.net/services@insynchq.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

I inserted the password and pressend enter the command finishes with an OK.
[image]

Comment: Screen shot:file:///home/freeland/Documents/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-10%2005:04:51.pngfile:///home/freeland/Documents/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-10%2005:04:51.png

Comment: Sory, screen shot didn't happen.

Comment: 2. I am not aware of running anything that wasn't installed from the iso package.

Comment: Another attempe at screen shot:

Comment: @ronfreeland updated  answer with how to add images.

Comment: 3.  I have tried multiple times to use sudo with password and always get the above.  I have no problem with the password forlogging in to Ubuntu at start up etc. , only sudo.

Comment: `sudo ls` does the same thing? The above command is through pipe, is not familiar to me maybe it asks for another password.

Comment: @ronfreeland I ran also the command: `wget -O - https://d2t3ff60b2tol4.cloudfront.net/services@insynchq.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -` and it remains suspended without executing nothing like in your screen, i found the command here: https://www.insynchq.com/linux. But after entering the password and pressing enter it finished. with an OK

Comment: I think you should enter the password when the screen is in waiting an press enter.

Comment: @ronfreeland updated, see answer, the problem is that because it is piped and probably the standard out is already used it doesn't prompt for password so you must introduce it and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't `sudo` talking; it is `wget` saying it successfully downloaded the file you asked it to.

Comment: I actualy ran the same command as him and it works after entering password and enter. +1 for confirming my answer. I suposed it was wget befor he put the screenshot.